# Please help me decrypt this letter

Tags: cipher

This may be an off topic question. But there is no other place that I think I will get help on this. This is serious.

One of my relative's daughter (12th standard) is missing and it seems like she is having some connection with some banned groups (her lover is one of them). Her parents got this letter from her book recently. They share it to me. It seems like Greek letters. I tried typing all it in Greek font in Google Translate and tried to translate, but the result was gibberish.

So I think this is some kind of code. Please help me find the code and understand what the letter is about. This is very serous and it's the matter of a young girl's life.

[image]
[image]

<s>You can down vote if you think this is not the place. But please don't delete or close this question at least for a couple of days so that someone can help.</s>

Moderators can close or delete this post as it got cracked already by M Oehm. Many thanks to him for his help.

Comment: I can't tell if you're for real or if it's just the background for the question

Comment: Ok. So I'm not sure this is the right place for this, but if it can help: because of the returning words, it seems like a simple substitution cipher for me. Someone who reads greek letters fluently can probably type it fast to have a digitized version.

Comment: Could it just be homework?

Comment: @AeJey you say you have already typed this into Google Translate. Please share the typed stuff and the first name of the girl, assuming her name starts with an 'h'.

Comment: What is their native tongue? I mean what language do you expect this to be decrypted to?

Comment: Yeah, I really really really hope this is fiction. I would hate to think that someone's life depends on the results of an internet post.

Comment: @Ali I'd guess English, judging by the English at the top of the paper.

Comment: Well, it's "Symbol font" rather than Greek; Greek has a lot of diacritics and it doesn't use the infnity symbol as letter as far as I know.

Comment: @Ali the letter seems to be malayalam written in english (transliteration)

Comment: This was real. Not any build up. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: Can the moderators please delete or hide this question if possible

Comment: I changed my mind. You can keep it here so that M Oehm's efforts wont go in weign. I will crop the image and update it tomorrow and will also add what the letter content is in english, since most of those who are here doesnt know malayalam.

Comment: Wait. So if this was real... did you go to the police?

Comment: I appreciate that you want to let us in on what the letter is about, but should you change your mind again and feel that the affair is best kept private, please go ahead and delete the post and don't let considerations about "wasting" my answer lost stop you.

Comment: Yes. Contacted the police as well.

Comment: M Oehm. Only moderators can delete this post

Comment: Why should mods close or delete questions with an accepted answer? You are still able to answer for a reason, even though an answer is accepted.

Comment: Actually @Aejey it is possible to delete your own questions.
Below the Tag (Cipher) there will be 4 options there, Share, Edit, Delete, Flag.

From there you are able to delete the question, if you choose to.

Comment: @ObviouslyJake: Since, this question already has an answer, and if I delete it myself, it can result in my account being blocked from asking questions.

Comment: @AeJey hope that you'll save her O:-)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is only a partial solution, a first step. The letter is written ...

> in English, at least part of it. It uses a monoalphabetic cipher where Greek letters and other symbols represent Latin letters. The letter uses abbreviations such as u = *you* and bcos = *because*. Punctuation is as usual in English and when we assume that the word with the apostrophe in the second line is either "can't" or "don't", we can guess that the first sentence reads:
>
>  *I don't think that I would b able to call u again.*

The whole letter reads:

> my muthu
>  I don't think that I would b able
>  to call u again. bcos n.n last
>  vilichitt shelf properly close
>  cheyythilla. so avarkk manassilayi
>  n.n vilichinenn. moreover phonil
>  ninn balance. kurannathum avarkk
>  manassilayi. so if u don't mind will u
>  give me a phone. ennala veetil
>  full preshnam aayirunnu. so inorder
>  to solve it, n.n sammathiciu n.n
>  phone eduth ninghale vilichini but
>  n.n parannu n.n ellam nirthi enn
>  parayananu vilichathenn. appune nalla
>  vishvasamanallo. athko.d n.n parannu
>  n.n oolude mumbil nilla vilichu paran
>  enn. oolum sammathiciu enghanayallo
>  and at last they believed. but
>  avarkk pediyund n.n ellam nirthu e?
>  parannathkond whether u would take
>  revenge on me. achan ene oriknasum
>  ninghala that shopul kanaruthe.
>  bcos he told eneyum oonn nilla
>  disturb aakunundengil case edikkam
>  karanam avarude vicharam n.n
>
>  ellam parannu. kainnittum backil nadakura-
>  nenn. ene muthal appukk half day class
>  aanu. n.n oolude kaiyil letter
>  kodukk.a. n.n vandu-moonuu days aayi
>  letter kodukhunnu. but she told
>  u was not there. n.n ene enkk
>  pattumengis mathre viliku ketto.
>  don't think anything. n.n ene athava
>  vilikunundengil new numberil mathre
>  vikikku pinna phone ennuk after onam
>  vacationu. shesham mathi enkk pediyu-
>  nd but enkk vilikan. vera no other
>  method. if u have some problem
>  then no need eykk kure parayanund
>  but epposhum vilikumb. enthenghlum
>  preshnam undakam.
>  enkk orupad orupad orupad
>  eshttanu ketto
>
>  yours lovingly ...

I've tried to keep the layout as in the original. Thanks to elias and noteness, who have contributed in the comments below, I now know that ...

> the non-English words are Malayalam. This language has its own script, but in the letter it is transliterated into Latin. I'm obviously not familiar with Malayalam, so there may well bet transcription errors in the Malayalam words. Sorry about that.
>
>  For completeness's sake, the alphabet is
>
>  `A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z`
>  `α β γ δ ∞ 6 ρ x λ . π σ μ ν ε Σ . ω φ ψ Λ Ω ~ . τ .`
>
>  (The τ (Y) isn't really a τ, but more like a latin t. The ν (N) could also be a θ. The dot in *n.n* stands for *ya* and the word, which occurs often, is *nyan*/*ñan*, or I in English. Two letters are unresolved: the t with the stroke to the left in *athko.d* and the u-shape in *kodukk.a*.)

Comment: http://malayalamenglishdictionary.com/index.php?option=com_glossary&id=2282

Comment: That is malayalam written in english! The last 2 lines mean: "I really really really love you" (orupad means really) that n.n is nan(njan w/e), which means I. I would try to translate it to english.

Comment: (actually orupad means a lot)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You are correct. Only a few words are missing. But was enough to guess the rest. Thanks again.

Comment: By the way just for curiosity, could you please tell me what that infinity symbol in second page represent

Comment: @noteness: Thanks, that's useful information. I don't know anything about Malayalam, so I can't really translate it.

Comment: @AeJey: Thanks. I'm glad you could use it, because I'm obvously no great help with the Malayalam. Which infinity symbol do you mean? Infinity resolves to e; I've added a decryption table for completeness.

Comment: I've seen that I had skipped two lines when I got confused with the Malayalam, which is all Greek to me. (Pun half-intended.) I guess you have already decoded them, but I've added them now.

Comment: @noteness Keep the account then, you will need it. I know what I'm talking about.